Is it possible to slice the argument array in Bash?
Consider the following script, which I simplified from this question.
#!/bin/bash

A=( foo bar "a  b c" 42 )
B=("${A[@]:1}")       # slice to the end of the array
echo "${B[@]}"

This works fine, but if I try to use similar syntax for the argument array $@ I get a syntax error:
#!/bin/bash

echo "$@"
B=("${$@:1}")       # slice to the end of the array

Executing:
./play  x y z
./play: line 4: ${$@:1}: bad substitution

Is there a different magic syntax for slicing the argument array?

You may want "${@:2}".  This is covered, with examples, in the Bash Reference Manual.

You don't write the $ twice when you do ${A[@]:1}, why do you think you need to do it twice for @?

Also see Bash: slice of positional parameters.

Actually, you can use shift command to shift arguments.

I am aware of shift, but I had other reasons for not modifying the original argument array. In particular, I was using exec to perform retries.

Slight change in the format:
$ cat play
echo "$@"
B=( "${@:1}" )
typeset -p B

Taking for a test drive:
$ ./play x y z
x y z
declare -a B=([0]="x" [1]="y" [2]="z")

Need to keep in mind that the 0th position ($0) is the name of the script:
B=( "${@:0}" )
typeset -p B
=> declare -a B=([0]="./play" [1]="x" [2]="y" [3]="z")

So you would want to shift the position one to the right (ie, change 1 to 2):
$ cat play
echo "$@"
B=( "${@:2}" )
typeset -p B

Taking for a test drive:
$ ./play x y z
x y z
declare -a B=([0]="y" [1]="z")

